# como dar target="_blank" em um botão

Tags: html, html5

queria saber se consigo colocar um target="_blank" neste input

```
<input type="button" value="sobre" onclick="location.href='sobre.html'">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="button" value="sobre" onclick="window.open('http://google.com','_blank')" >
```

Comment: @Filipi, tenta dessa nova forma.

Comment: muito obrigado, agora funcionou

Comment: `formtarget="_blank"`? onde está isso no código? O que isso faz?

Answer (score 0):

Você deve utilizar a propriedade `target` na tag `a`.

Tente utilizar assim:

```
<a href="sobre.html" target="_blank" />
```

Comment: olha, sei desse tipo, mas eu estou procurando como botão mas obrigado por responder

Comment: @Filipi Acho que essa resposta seria a forma mais plausível. Da forma como você quer fazer e a outra resposta que foi dada, acaba utilizando o Javascript para uma coisa desnecessária. Poderia ser feito simplesmente com o target="_blank". Se que um botão faça isso, que tal colocar a formatação do botão na tag `<a>`? Acho que seria mais simples.